# VS Code opens powershell cmd even though I set Windows' cmd as default

Tags: visual-studio-code

As in the topic, how do I change it so that powershell DOESN'T open and cmd terminal does open when starting the IDE? Windows' cmd is set as default but still powershell opens when I start the IDE